# What's this music used when Lelouch is giving new orders in ep. 2 of R2?

Tags: music, code-geass

What's the section of the soundtrack used in the second episode of R2 at 8:00, after Kallen defeats a Knightmare and Lelouch gives new orders, called?

Comment: Is this after Kallen defeats a knightmare, and Lelouch makes new orders?

Comment: @Maroon yes that's it

Answer (score 1):

I think it's unreleased album, the #9 song Knightmare Assault. Unfortunately I don't have a download link because I haven't found one myself =/.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEK28DBU2_I&index=9&list=PLb4mticUuCmQSnQpXJDttkzbhOxAdnGWf

Answer (score 0):

I think it sounds like a version of Sensibility, only piano only: [OST on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKK6QsilgqI&ab_channel=GriffionLiBritannia)

Comment: FWIW the section in question seems to be using a harpsichord, and some strings also come in later.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It's called Turning the Tide. It's an unreleased OST. There are some edits on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nh8CS8PM7vk
and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRL6tTLYQwU

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any idea where is the name from? In particular, I would expect that if it wasn't released, the name would not be known (although I could be wrong).

Comment: @Maroon I have no idea. Maybe the youtuber who created it called it that way, because it fits the scenes in the anime where it's played.