# What is the name of song from Code Geass in episode 5 when the Lancelot is saving Jeremiah?

Tags: music, code-geass

What is the name of song from Code Geass in episode 5 when the Lancelot is saving Jeremiah? I can't find it or any covers of it anywhere, it starts at 1:16 here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_xS6y1-92s&t=66

Comment: It would be nice to give an exact timestamp of where in the episode this scene happens (I assume you're talking about the piece from 1:16 onwards in the YouTube clip?) if you have the episode handy.

Comment: Yes that is the correct part of the video.

Comment: For reference, this scene starts at 18:57 of the Crunchyroll stream of episode 5. Note that the link is dead now, so it may be a good idea to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

It's an unreleased piece from the soundtrack called **Knightmare Assault**. You can find it here:

[Code Geass: Unreleased Album - 09 Knightmare Assault](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEK28DBU2_I&index=9&list=PLb4mticUuCmQSnQpXJDttkzbhOxAdnGWf)

Prior to this, fans ad dubbed it 'Turning the Tides', so you will find some covers of it under that name:

http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/File:Turning_the_Tide_(Code_Geass_Unreleased_Music)

---

**Source**

<sup>[What's this music used when Lelouch is giving new orders in ep. 2 of R2?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/32412/whats-this-music-used-when-lelouch-is-giving-new-orders-in-ep-2-of-r2)</sup>